# Trying to add entries in NSArray to NSDictionary, but values in NSDictionary are getting deallocated

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsdictionary

I have three Deck Objects which are mostly just wrappers around NSArray objects containing Card objects. Initially, all the Card objects are in deck1, and eventually move through deck2 and deck3.

I also have an NSDictionary object that maps NSString objects to Card objects. I use the cards in deck1 to build this lookup table at the beginning of the game like this...

```
-(NSDictionary *)buildLookupTable {
    NSMutableDictionary *lookup = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (Card *card in self.cards) {
        NSString *lookupCode = [self buildCode:card];
        [lookup setObject:card forKey:lookupCode];
    }

    return lookup;
}
```

I then pass the NSDictionary and the Decks to a layer object, but when I attempt to lookup a given Card based on a NSString, I get "-[CFString hash]: message sent to deallocated instance", but I can easily find the Card I'm looking for, not deallocated, in deck1 or deck2.

The NSString I'm using as a key to retrieve the desired value isn't deallocated, nor is the NSDictionary itself. I have even iterated over the return from the NSDictionary object's allValues method, and none of those are deallocated either.

What other deallocated objects could there be?

Edit-version2: 
I've narrowed it down a bit.

In the lookup code this works

```
NSString *key = @"4-0"; //(NSString *)sprite.userData;
return [self.cardLookup objectForKey:key];
```

but this doesn't

```
NSString *key = (NSString *)sprite.userData; // value is @"4-0"
return [self.cardLookup objectForKey:key];
```

In the debugger sprite.userData looks fine.

sprite.userData is defined in the Card class buildSprite method as...

```
sprite.userData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i",self.x, self.y];
```

It looks like calling copyWithZone on key doesn't work (like it would for any other NSString).

Comment: It does this already, there is an error in your code somewhere (not the posted code). Also specify if you are using ARC.

Comment: you should post the other parts of your code that may be causing the bug

Comment: The compiler I'm using is Apple LLVM compiler 4.1, so I think I am using ARC.

Comment: @user467384 how do you perform the lookup? And what does the `buildCode` method do?

Comment: Did you iterate over allKeys and check them?

Comment: With all due respect, you don't "think" you're using ARC, you **know** whether you're using it or not.  You must code differently depending, so you'd damn well better know.

Comment: I iterated over all keys and all values in the lookup in the onTouchesEnded method.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!

The problem was with the sprite.userData object and how it was created.

```
sprite.userData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i",self.x, self.y];
```

Evidently sprite.userData was getting released (thought the Xcode debugger seemed to know what it was, possibly because I had zombie objects enabled). The correct version is...

```
sprite.userData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i",self.x, self.y] retain];
```

Comment: So you're not using ARC.  And sprite.userData does not retain.